# Javascript function only works once. Any idea why?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

HTML

I am trying to create a todolist application. I wanted to make each task list to be removed with faded transition. I achieved it already but the problem with my code is that it only hide the first div area.

```
<div id="task">
            <input type="checkbox" id="completed">
            <h2>Buy some fruits</h2>
        </div>
        <div id="task">
            <input type="checkbox" id="completed">
            <h2>Buy some fruits</h2>
        </div>
```

JQuery

```
 $("#completed").change(function(){$("#item").fadeToggle("fast", "linear")});
```

Comment: you have more than one element with the same id in the page.

Comment: You should use ```class``` instead of ```ID```, because Id should be unique in context and only return first element of with same ```ID```

Answer (score 5):

Dont use mutipple `id's` on same page use `class` instead

```
<div class="task">
   <input type="checkbox" class="completed">
   <h2>Buy some fruits</h2>
</div>
<div class="task">
   <input type="checkbox" class="completed">
   <h2>Buy some fruits</h2>
</div>

 $(".completed").change(function(){$("#item").fadeToggle("fast", "linear")});

// same apply to your #item
```

Answer (score 0):

You should not have multiple elements with the same `id`. The whole point of this attribute is to uniquely identify an element.

Replace it with something like:

```
  <input type="checkbox" class="completed">
```

And your javascript accordingly:

```
  $(".completed").change(function(){$("#item").fadeToggle("fast", "linear")});
```

This should sort your problem out.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<div>
    <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox">
    <h2>Buy some fruits</h2>
</div>
<div>
    <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox">
    <h2>Buy some fruits</h2>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(".checkbox").change(function(){$(this).parent().fadeToggle("fast", "linear")});
</script>
```

OR

```
<div>
    <input type="checkbox">
    <h2>Buy some fruits</h2>
</div>
<div>
    <input type="checkbox">
    <h2>Buy some fruits</h2>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("input[type=checkbox]").change(function(){$(this).parent().fadeToggle("fast", "linear")});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

**`id`** of both input elements are same.

you can use class instead of `id`.

like below

```
$(".completed").change(function(){ } $(this).hide();});
```

pls modify this code as per u r